# Cannot access router page or ping gateway, but internet works?

Tags: router, gateway

I have a netgear router with several computer connected to it.  I can access the internet fine but cannot access the router page.  When I try to ping 192.168.1.1 it times out.  This seems really strange to me.  Has anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 3):

Are you certain that 192.168.1.1 is your gateway address?  My Netgear router at our cabin uses 192.168.0.1 by default, although I'm sure it varies from model to model.

If that *is* the correct gateway, have you reset the router?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a linux system you have utilities as Avahi-browser and nmap that can help you find services and hosts on your local network. Avahi-browser is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Check the gateway address on your host machine - is it what you expect?

Check that you don't have wireless switched on in case you are unwittingly connecting to the internet through someone else's connection.